# Print original input value to screen

Tags: c++

So I am working on writing a code that takes any integer input  and reverses them
Here is my program so far. I am trying to get it to print say I enter 1234 my output should say:
'1234' in reverse is '4321'
but it prints out '0' in reverse is '4321'
does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int number;int reverse = 0;  

    cout << "Input any integer value\n ";
    cin >> number;

    for (; number != 0; )
    {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }

    cout << "'"<< number << "'" <<" in reverse is " << "'"<< reverse<<"'"<< endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You are changing the value of number here in your for loop:
      
    number = number / 10;

And then you are printing this number out.

Comment: unless you need the number as an value of type `int` somewhere else, I would suggest you to read it as a string an use [`std::string::reverse()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing number in cycle. So, I can only suggest to save it in different variable like below. Or implement different algorithm.

```
cin >> number;
int original = number;
....
cout << "'" << original << "'" ...
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked perfectly. That's what i was thinking just couldn't get it inputted right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
     int numb,b,c,rev=0;
     cout<<"plz enter the number"<<endl;
      cin>>numb;
     do
     {
     c=numb%10;        
    rev=(rev*10)+c; 
    numb=numb/10;
     }
      while(numb!=0);
     cout<<"The reverse of the number"<<rev<<endl;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Also some code indentation and meaningful variables names would be nice